# CSS sprites and background positioning

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am currently working on implementing a star-rating widget. Which needs to make use of a sprite file, which looks as the following

[image: Sprite with ratings]

I have my html structured as following

**HTML**

```
 <span id="star-ratings" class="containers">
      <span id="ratings"></span>
 </span>
```

I have the following CSS, which is where i am unsure of in terms of displaying the stars

```
#star-ratings, #ratings{
    background:url(../images/star-sprite.png) 0 15.8px repeat-x;
    display: block;
    width: 78px;
    height: 14px;
}
```

To further explain my thought process, i am passing down a rating value which can range from 0-5 through my javascript and then calculating the final width size and applying it to the inner span.

Currently i am trying to display the initial start, which is the empty star. But instead i see all the stars on my page.

Comment: please show yhe javascript code too..or if you could reproduce the issue in a fiddle or so, it would be really helpfull...

Comment: This can be implemented without any images and Javascript. http://lea.verou.me/2011/08/accessible-star-rating-widget-with-pure-css/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Explanation

Let's use the [`image`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZSMMj.png) you provided in the example. The image have **80px** width (actually its 79px but i'm rounding up), **14px** height and **5** states: **0%**, **25%**, **50%**, **75%** and **100%**.

To use the image as a sprite, we will create a base class called `.star` and assign the height of the image (**14px**) and the width of a single state, which would be **16px** (80px / 5 states).

The default state will be the first one in the sprite (**0%**). Afterwards, we create an extra CSS for each aditional state: **25%**, **50%**, **75%** and **100%**.

Each class will have a different value for the `background-position` attribute, based on the state width.

## Example

Here is an example using the image provided by the user as a sprite.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <style>
    .rating {
      margin: 25px;
    }
    .rating label {
      font-weight: bold;
      display: block;
    }
    .star {
      display: inline-block;
      width: 16px;
      height: 14px;
      background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZSMMj.png');
      background-repeat: none;
    }
    .star-25 {
      background-position: -16px 0;
    }
    .star-50 {
      background-position: -32px 0;
    }
    .star-75 {
      background-position: -48px 0;
    }
    .star-100 {
      background-position: -64px 0;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="rating">
    <label>1/5 (20%)</label>
    <span class="star star-100"></span>
    <span class="star"></span>
    <span class="star"></span>
    <span class="star"></span>
    <span class="star"></span>
  </div>

  <div class="rating">
    <label>4/5 (80%)</label>
    <span class="star star-100"></span>
    <span class="star star-100"></span>
    <span class="star star-100"></span>
    <span class="star star-100"></span>
    <span class="star"></span>
  </div>

  <div class="rating">
    <label>8/10 (80%)</label>
    <span class="star star-100"></span>
    <span class="star star-100"></span>
    <span class="star star-100"></span>
    <span class="star star-100"></span>
    <span class="star star-100"></span>
    <span class="star star-100"></span>
    <span class="star star-100"></span>
    <span class="star star-100"></span>
    <span class="star"></span>
    <span class="star"></span>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

## Additional example

Here is another example using only CSS (no images), for additional studies purposes. Based on [Accessible star rating widget with pure CSS](http://lea.verou.me/2011/08/accessible-star-rating-widget-with-pure-css/), provided by the user [`connexo`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3744304/connexo) in the comments.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

  <meta charset="UTF-8">

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <style type="text/css">
    body {
      margin: 25px;
    }
    .center {
      padding: 10px 0;
    }
    input[type=number] {
      font-size: 22px;
      padding: 5px;
      width: 50px;
    }
    .star-rating {
      display: inline-block;
    }
    .star {
      font-size: 30px;
    }
    .star:before {
      content: '★';
      color: #ddd;
      text-shadow: 2px 2px #bbb;
    }
    .star-rating[data-value="1"] .star:nth-child(-n + 1):before,
    .star-rating[data-value="2"] .star:nth-child(-n + 2):before,
    .star-rating[data-value="3"] .star:nth-child(-n + 3):before,
    .star-rating[data-value="4"] .star:nth-child(-n + 4):before,
    .star-rating[data-value="5"] .star:nth-child(-n + 5):before,
    .star-rating[data-value="6"] .star:nth-child(-n + 6):before,
    .star-rating[data-value="7"] .star:nth-child(-n + 7):before,
    .star-rating[data-value="8"] .star:nth-child(-n + 8):before,
    .star-rating[data-value="9"] .star:nth-child(-n + 9):before,
    .star-rating[data-value="10"] .star:nth-child(-n + 10):before {
      color: #fff455;
      text-shadow: 2px 2px #c3bb41;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>

  <div class="center">

    <input type="number" value="0" min="0" max="3" class="star-control" data-target="#star-1">

    <div id="star-1" class="star-rating" data-value="0">
      <span class="star"></span>
      <span class="star"></span>
      <span class="star"></span>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="center">

    <input type="number" value="0" min="0" max="5" class="star-control" data-target="#star-2">

    <div id="star-2" class="star-rating" data-value="0">
      <span class="star"></span>
      <span class="star"></span>
      <span class="star"></span>
      <span class="star"></span>
      <span class="star"></span>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="center">

    <input type="number" value="0" min="0" max="10" class="star-control" data-target="#star-3">

    <div id="star-3" class="star-rating" data-value="0">
      <span class="star"></span>
      <span class="star"></span>
      <span class="star"></span>
      <span class="star"></span>
      <span class="star"></span>
      <span class="star"></span>
      <span class="star"></span>
      <span class="star"></span>
      <span class="star"></span>
      <span class="star"></span>
    </div>

  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    function onStarControlChange() {

      var $this = $(this),
        value = $this.val(),
        target = $this.data('target');

      $(target).attr('data-value', value);

    }

    $('.star-control').on('change', onStarControlChange);
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: i see how the positioning works, but i am still trying to grasp on how to show, for example a rating of 4/5 with first four stars with position -64px 0 and last start with position -16px 0. Am i approaching this right way?

Comment: To achieve a 4/5 rating you could use 4 stars with 100% and 1 star with 0%. In fact there's no "right way". There are plenty of ways of doing that!

Comment: sorry i still didn't follow how would i show the 4 stars with 100%

Comment: oh i see, i might have forgotten to mention the ratings value is dynamic, it can range from 0-5, so you could have ratings of 2.45. That would adding those classes dynamically to the span element and covering those for every possible scenario in your js

Answer (score 2):

You have used the width for all the images combined while you need to define the width for that particular image. Modify the place of the internal images using `background-position`

```css
#star-ratings,
#ratings {
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZSMMj.png) 0 0 repeat-x;
  display: block;
  width: 14px; /* Modified */
  height: 14px;
  background-position: 0px;
}

.ratings1 {
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZSMMj.png) 0 0 repeat-x;
  display: block;
  width: 14px; 
  height: 14px;
  background-position: -16px;
}
```

```html
First rating
<span id="star-ratings" class="containers">
      <span id="ratings"></span>
</span>
Second rating
<span id="star-ratings" class="containers">
      <span class="ratings1"></span>
</span>
```

Comment: shouldn't width be the size to contain all the 5 stars

Comment: No, that is covered by the background-position. Try adding `background-position: 15px` to see the last star.

Comment: ok i see but what if i am passing the rating dynamically say 4/5, then first four stars need to filled and the last star needs to be empty

Comment: So you will need to create separate class for each sprite image, then assign something like `if(rating == 4) { showImgClass4(); }` in JavaScript.